# How can I merge two audio tracks into one track but have one louder than the other?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mkv

I have a mkv file with an audio track (raw AAC file with ADTS headers) and I would like to merge it with another audio file that has my comments on it (AAC m4a file recorded with my phone.

I know I can merge both audio files in one track with te following command:

> ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i audio.m4a -i audio.aac -filter_complex
> "[1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:a:1 aac copy test.mkv

However I would like my voice (audio.m4a) to be around 40% louder than the original audio (audio.acc). How can i do that?